# Converting an empty string input to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a code like this to find the arithmetical mean for numbers the user has typed in but for some reason the program couldn't convert string to float in the end. What should I change?

```
print("I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! \n")
jnr = 0; sum = 0
negative = "-"
while True:
    x = input(f"Type in {jnr}. nr. (To end press Enter): ")
    if negative not in x:
        jnr += 1
    elif negative in x:
        pass
    elif x == "": break
    sum = sum + float(x)

print("Aritmethmetical mean for these numbers is: "+str(round(sum/(jnr-1), 2)))
```

I got his Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\siims\Desktop\Koolitööd\individuaalne proge.py", line 11, in
>    sum = sum + float(x) ValueError: could not convert string to
>   float

Comment: using round() is the reason for your problem.

Comment: What should I do about the round(). Just take it out?

Comment: What is the error that you get?  Please provide any tracebacks or input or output in your question.

Comment: round() will not display a float value.

Comment: `round()` is not the error. The error comes from the fact that you're trying to call `float(x)` which is an invalid string to convert when the user press enter.

Comment: @scharette oh yeah, you are right. I didnt noticed that.

Comment: @scharette But what should I do then for it to work?

Comment: @SiimSalmi see my answer I think it works as expected

Comment: What value do you try to input?

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment the error comes from the fact that calling `float(x)` when the user uses `Enter` result in the error. The easiest way to fix your code without changing everything is by checking first if the input is `""`. That way you will not be trying to convert an empty string to float.

```
print("I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! \n")
jnr = 0; 
sum = 0
negative = "-"
while True:
    x = input(f"Type in {jnr}. nr. (To end press Enter): ")

    if x == "":
        break
    elif negative not in x:
        jnr += 1
        sum = sum + float(x)


print("Aritmethmetical mean for these numbers is: "+str(round(sum/(jnr-1), 2)))
```

Comment: @FredLarson can you please elaborate? I can't understand what you're underlying.

Comment: If `negative not in x` is false, `negative in x` must be true. The second test is redundant, so eliminate it. Just `else:` will do.

Comment: Brain fade -- I had said `elif:` when I meant `else:`. Sorry.

Comment: @FredLarson Ok haha, now I see. I wanted to keep the code as original as possible. You are right, but using `else` would also be redundant in my opinion, since `else: pass` will be ignored by the compiler...

Comment: You're right, `else: pass` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a string to a float but it is an invalid string if you are using the string for that purpose. I would just continue asking until the user gives the right input, like this:

```
def float_input(s):
    while True:
        try:
            x = input(s)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Try again.')
        else:
            break
    return x
```

Then, instead of `input`, use `float_input` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of your code :

```
print("I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! \n")
jnr = 0; sum = 0
while True:
    x = int(input())
    if x>1:
        jnr += 1
    elif x<1:
        pass

    if x == 0:
        break
    sum += float(x)
    print(sum)



print("Aritmethmetical mean for these numbers is: {}".format(sum/jnr))
```

output:

```
I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! 

9
9
9
9
9
0
Aritmethmetical mean for these numbers is: 9.0
```

Pythonic way:

You can find mean by:

```
print("I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! \n")
inp=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(sum(inp)/len(inp))
```

output:

```
I'm going to find the arithmetical mean! 

9 9 9 9 9
9.0
```